# Meaning of "hats and cats"?

Tags: meaning, idiom-meaning

In the film High Society, Daxter-Haven has the following line when addressing a room full of people:

> Dear gentle folk of Newport -- Or maybe I should say, "hats and cats"?

What is the meaning of "hats and cats" in this context?

Comment: Given that Dexter-Haven is a jazz musician in the film, I'm going to guess that "cats" is "hepcats"

Comment: Cat: (orig. US black) in orig. jazz-orientated uses .
(a) a jazz musician. 

(b) a smartly dressed, fashion conscious man; thus sharp cat. https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/yxhtiiq

Answer (score 3):

The intended meaning of "hats and cats" is evidently "ladies and gentlemen." Here is the entry for *hat* in Robert Gold, *A Jazz Lexicon* (1964):

> **hat,** *n.* {obscene semantic development: i.e., an analogy is drawn between putting on  hat and mounting a woman in coitus; some currency esp. among Negro jassmen since c. 1940} See quote. — 1963 *Hiptionary*, p. 8. *hat:* girl, chick {jazz sense}, wife.

The term *hat* also appears in Hyman Goldin, *Dictionary of American Underworld Lingo* (1950) in the context of prison slang:

> **Hat** (a "hunk of hat"). A passive pederast; a fag [defined elsewhere in the same dictionary as "A passive homosexual, oral or pederastic"]; a loose woman. "Mickey's partner (criminal associate) turned out to be a hunk of hat in the big house (prison)."

And here is *A Jazz Lexicon*'s entry for *cat*:

> **cat,** *n.* {semantic etym. obscure; 1946 quot. logical but of doubtful validity; most prob. shortened form of general and Negro slang *tomcat* (i.e., a female-chasing  male); also poss. related to the itinerant nature of early jazzmen: cf. 1930 *American Tramp and Underworld Slang*, s.v. *cat:* "Itinerant worker ... Possibly so called because he slinks about like a homeless cat"; see 1958 quot for semantic development; according to jazzmen, Louis Armstrong introduced the term into jazz slang c. 1922, very widely current since} See quot. — 1936 *Swing That Music*, p. 42. All jazz musicians from New Orleans called each other "cats" and still do. — 1937 *New Yorker* 17 April, p. 31. Dance musicians are known as cats. — 1946 *Really the Blues*, p. 218. They even called each other *cats* approvingly because they wanted to be as alert and keen-sighted as an alley cat. — 1958 *Publications of the American Dialect Society*, Nov., p. 44. *cat:* orig. one who was "hep." Obsolete in this sense; now, any person. (Thus, a musician can now speak of a "square cat"—a contradiction in terms in the '30's.) — 1959 Esquire, Nov., p. 70I. *cat:* in the finest sense, a person who swings with life.

The film *High Society* was released in 1956 and, as user888379
notes in a comment beneath the posted question, the line in question is spoken by a jazzman. It seems reasonable to infer that the screenwriter (John Patrick, working from the script for the 1939 play *The Philadelphia Story*) was aware of jazz terms such as *hat* (for woman) and *cat* (for man) that had come into use in that milieu by 1950.

Jonathon Green, *Cassell's Dictionary of Slang*, second edition (2005) indicates that *hat* in the relevant sense was in use into the 1960s:

> **hat** *n.* ... **5** {1940s–1960s} (*US Black*) a woman, esp. a wife or sweetheart